# How to calculate $\int \sqrt{(\cos{x})^2-a^2} \, dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals, elliptic-functions

How to calculate: 
$$\int \sqrt{(\cos{x})^2-a^2} \, dx$$

Comment: This seems distinctly nontrivial - I get elliptic integrals. I doubt it is expressible in elementary functions. Where did it come from? I can do 1 instead of $a^2$ though, pretty easily. That good enough?

Comment: I'm trying to find the probability that two cars be in reach after time $\tau$ .. I assumed a model and I'm stuck with that

Comment: Do you want the indefinite integral or do you need actually a certain definite integral? (very often in applications one need to integral from a point where the argument of the $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is zero to another point with these properties)

Comment: Is a bounded by anything?

Comment: Further - from this integral, how will you determine the probability? As this will likely have an imaginary component, will you just mod the answer?

Comment: Maybe you should post your probability problem too.

Answer (score 8):

$$\int\sqrt{\cos^2 x-a^2}\;dx  =\frac{1}{k} \int \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2x}\;dx$$ where $k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$ As this seems to come from a physical problem, introduce limits and look into [elliptic integrals of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html).

Comment: Does it makes a difference if the integral is $\int_a^b{\int_0^{2\pi}{\sqrt{y^2(\cos^2{\theta}-1)+1}}\mathrm{d}\theta}\mathrm{d}y$?

I thought I can start with the inner integral and simplify it to what I wrote. But, I don't want to do the elliptic integral thing!

Answer (score 3):

In SWP (Scientific WorkPlace), with Local MAPLE kernel,  I got the following evaluation

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
I &:&=\int \sqrt{\cos ^{2}x-a^{2}}dx \\
&=&-\frac{\sqrt{\sin ^{2}x}}{\sin x}a^{2}\text{EllipticF}\left( \left( \cos
x\right) \frac{\text{csgn}\left( a^{\ast }\right) }{a},\text{csgn}\left(
a\right) a\right)  \\
&&-\text{EllipticF}\left( \left( \cos x\right) \frac{\text{csgn}\left(
a^{\ast }\right) }{a},\text{csgn}\left( a\right) a\right)  \\
&&+\text{EllipticE}\left( \left( \cos x\right) \frac{\text{csgn}\left(
a^{\ast }\right) }{a},\text{csgn}\left( a\right) a\right) F
\end{eqnarray*}$$

where

$$F=\sqrt{\frac{-\cos ^{2}x+a^{2}}{a^{2}}}\sqrt{\cos ^{2}x-a^{2}}\text{csgn}\left( a^{\ast }\right) \frac{a}{-\cos ^{2}x+a^{2}}$$

As an example:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \sqrt{\cos ^{2}x-2^{2}}dx &=&\frac{\sqrt{\sin ^{2}x}}{\sin x}3\text{EllipticF}\left( \frac{1}{2}\cos x,2\right)  \\
&&+\text{EllipticE}\left( \frac{1}{2}\cos x,2\right) \frac{\sqrt{-\cos
^{2}x+4}}{\sqrt{\cos ^{2}x-4}}
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate it in Matlab? It will really help me.

Comment: @Osama Gamal: No, I don't. I have no Matlab intalled and has never worked with it.

Comment: @OsamaGamal You should just be able to type `lookfor elliptic` and find something that estimates them. I'd be very surprised if MATLAB didn't have something for that.

Comment: @OsamaGamal In fact, [here it is](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ellipke.html)